# Kendo UI: Need to export a multicolored-cells grid to excel

Tags: jquery, excel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Depending on cell values, I need to color code different cells of the grid. I do not color the whole column but different cells of different columns and this can be pretty random.
I tried to do it with Kendo templates but could not figure out a way to isolate individual cells and giving them a separate background color. So I used jQuery to access td elements with cell values corresponding to my needs and then giving the td elements a class to change the background color. So that's done.
Now, I need to export this grid - along with the colored backgrounds of cells - to excel. But Kendo's ootb Export to Excel functionality doesn't colorify individual cells. Is there any way to configure the datasource in such a way that would meet my needs? Or, failing that, any other 3rd party tool that would let me make excel files easily without doing much tinkering to my datasource object?

Comment: Can you please provide an example? You can build one here: http://dojo.telerik.com/

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/alternating-rows there is a dojo link with example

Answer (score 1):

As far as having the export to excel color the cells, it can be done but not via the datasource. Happily, you won't need to touch the datasource.

What I did (I only needed to do rows) was I grabbed all of the kendo grid rows background colors, set them in a temp array, then iterated through the rows of the sheet object and set the colors via the following attributes (in the excel sheet):

(i and j are indexes from loops)

```
//background color
sheet.rows[i].cells[j].background = equivalent row value from grid array
//text color
sheet.rows[i].cells[j].color = equivalent row value from grid array
```

So if you use a 2-d array to grab the colors from your grid then just recreate that structure in the sheets object and set the attributes.

Comment: Where do you get the sheet object from? Does kendo provide a method for that?

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook They're from the Workbook object.